# Flask session member not persisting across requests

Tags: python, flask

I'm writing a quick app to view a giant XML file with some AJAX style calls to `viewgroup`. My problem is `session['groups']` not persisting. I have some old array with only 4 members that is stuck somewhere (cookie?..). That value is present when `view` is called. I then overwrite that session member with info from the recently opened xml file that contains 20+ members.

However, when `viewgroup` is called the session variable has reverted to the old value with only 4 members in the array!

Code followed by output. Note the 3 `sessionStatus()` calls

```
def sessionStatus():
    print "# of groups in session = " + str(len(session['groups']))

@app.route('/')
def index():
    cams = [file for file in os.listdir('xml/') if file.lower().endswith('xml')]
    return render_template('index.html', cam_files=cams)

@app.route('/view/<xmlfile>')
def view(xmlfile):
    path = 'xml/' + secure_filename(xmlfile)
    print 'opening ' + path
    xmlf = open(path, 'r')
    tree = etree.parse(xmlf)
    root = tree.getroot()
    p = re.compile(r'Group')
    groups = []
    for g in root:
        if (p.search(g.tag) is not None) and (g.attrib['Comment'] != 'Root'):
            groups.append(Group(g.attrib['Comment']))
    sessionStatus()
    session['groups'] = groups
    sessionStatus()
    return render_template('view.html', xml=xmlfile, groups=groups)

@app.route('/viewgroup/<name>')
def viewGroup(name):
    groups = session['groups']
    sessionStatus()        
    if groups is None or len(groups) == 0:
        raise Exception('invalid group name')
    groups_filtered = [g for g in groups if g.name == name]
    if len(groups_filtered) != 1:
        raise Exception('invalid group name', groups_filtered)
    group = groups_filtered[0]
    prop_names = [p.name for p in group.properties]
    return prop_names
```

Output

```
opening xml/d.xml
# of groups in session = 5
# of groups in session = 57
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Aug/2011 17:27:29] "GET /view/d.xml HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Aug/2011 17:27:29] "GET /static/ivtl.css HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Aug/2011 17:27:29] "GET /static/jquery.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Aug/2011 17:27:29] "GET /static/raphael-min.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Aug/2011 17:27:29] "GET /static/ivtl.css HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Aug/2011 17:27:29] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 -
# of groups in session = 5
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Aug/2011 17:27:31] "GET /viewgroup/DeviceInformation HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

I need all 57 groups to stay around. Any hints?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The data was simply too big to serialize into the session. Now I generate a key into a global dict and store that key in the session.

```
gXmlData[path] = groups
```

There's the problem that the global dict will stay around forever with more and more keys but the process isn't meant to live long.

Comment: You could use redis backend to store the dictionary. There is a nice functionality to store data in a key with expiry date (http://redis.io/commands/setex). So on first set you define expiry with kind of session timeout. Than on each get you either prolong expiry or return session expired (http://redis.io/commands/expire). Value data size limit is pretty big (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5606106/what-is-the-maximum-value-size-you-can-store-in-redis).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your data is too big.

If your data is larger than 4KB, a server-side session is needed. Have a look at [Flask-Session](https://flask-session.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).