# How big of an array can be stored in Redis database?

Tags: laravel, redis

What could be the biggest size of an array to be `put` in Redis cache?

I'm considering storing data temporarily in Redis cache. The overall process of storing data is like this -

// This is from Laravel framework (PHP)

```
$existing_data = Cache::store('redis')->get('existing_data');

array_push($existing_data, ['elem1' => $elem1, 'elem2' => $elem2, 'elem3' => $elem3]);

Cache::store('redis')->put('existing_data', $existing_data, 30*60);
```

As you can see, the size of array will keep on increasing and I'm suspecting about 150,000 - 200,000 sub-arrays in my `$existing_data`; before I'll pull them from Redis and store them in my database.

My redis server has 1.5GB memory; and I'm wondering if there's any limit it will put when storing the array.

Comment: The limits are here... https://redis.io/topics/data-types

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the maximum value size you can store in redis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5606106/what-is-the-maximum-value-size-you-can-store-in-redis)